# How to convert entire JSON response of Web API to CSV file using python?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I would like to convert entire string or "gudid" of [such page](https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/api/v2/devices/lookup.json?di=08717648200274) to CSV file by python code.

The results of the following code contains only part of the content (39 lines) of the above URL (125 lines after formatted by ms-python.python).

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
RESORCE_INFORMATION = "https://accessgudid.nlm.nih.gov/api/v2/devices/lookup.json"

PARAMTERS = "di=08717648200274" 

TARGET = RESORCE_INFORMATION+'?'+PARAMTERS
print(TARGET)
response = requests.get(TARGET) 
# print(response.text)

json_dict = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.DataFrame(json_dict["gudid"])
df.to_csv("device_lookup.csv")
```

How do I convert entire response from above URL to CSV file?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Below will work if it is not mandatory to use data frame.
also I see a filtering criteria, you converting only "gudud" column to df, is there any reason?...if thats not required remove that filtering

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_dict["gudid"])

import csv
import json

json_dict = json.loads(response.text)
f = open('data.csv')
csv_file = csv.writer(f)
for item in json_dict:
    f.writerow(item)

f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  However, above code got an error.'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'writerow'<br>The following my code is not as expected.<br>json_dict = json.loads(response.text)
f = open('data.csv', 'w')
csv_file = csv.writer(f)
for item in json_dict:
    print(item)
    csv_file.writerow(item)
f.close()